# How to solve mounting error when running docker?

Tags: docker

I am running docker on an Amazon m2.large instance running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
(GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64).

Here is the output of `docker info`

```
Containers: 10
Images: 72
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:16-475138-pool
 Data file: /mnt/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata file: /mnt/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 2574.9 Mb
 Data Space Total: 102400.0 Mb
 Metadata Space Used: 4.5 Mb
 Metadata Space Total: 2048.0 Mb
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-24-generic
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Here is the output of `docker version`:

```
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 990021a
```

I am running docker as follows:

```
docker run \
   --volume /mnt/dir_1:/outputs:rw \
   --volume /mnt/dir_2:/inputs:ro \
   --detach=false \
   --cidfile=/mnt/dir_3/container_id \
   my_image \
   arg_1 \
   arg_2
```

However I get the following error:

```
2014/07/01 22:26:59 Error response from daemon: Error mounting '/dev/mapper/docker-202:16-475138-e1d927e16afbf1537f66bb0b6f3df56be7160cea7abefe19059aff2c00c55a0a-init' on '/mnt/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e1d927e16afbf1537f66bb0b6f3df56be7160cea7abefe19059aff2c00c55a0a-init': invalid argument
```

I already ran this command successfully once and it produced the expected output. Now however it returns this error. How do I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this appears to be to move away from the default driver 'devmapper' and use the 'btrfs' driver which a correspondingly formatted filesystem. An even more performant option, is to use the 'overlayfs' driver.

Comment: Is there any recent info that supports this solution?